# El uso de la herramienta AzCopy para migrar datos a un blob Storage, tengo una duda

Tags: azure, blob, almacenamiento, azure-storage, migracion

¿Cómo muestra cuando falla y cómo retomar?, te doy un ejemplo, tienes 100 archivos que migrar, falló el número 3, 50 y 90. ¿Cómo sé cuáles fallaron? ¿Cómo se puede hacer para reprocesar, retomar o enviar solo los que fallaron?
** Los archivos son carpetas e imágenes.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.